# Is it possible to log all HTTP request headers with Apache?

Tags: apache, logging

How to make a record into the logfile the contents of the HTTP request header (all) as received by apache?

Currently my apache combined log format configuration is:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{Cookie}i\"" combined
```

I understand that it is possible to do it so:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" \"%{Cookie}i\" \"%{heading name}i\" \"%{heading name}i\" \"%{heading name}i\"" combined
```

but it is not logical and it is not possible to know which headers will be.

Answer (score 111):

[mod_log_forensic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html) is what you want, but it may not be included/available with your Apache install by default.

Here is how to use it.

```
LoadModule log_forensic_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_log_forensic.so 
<IfModule log_forensic_module> 
ForensicLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/forensic.log
</IfModule>
```

Note: Your path may vary, such as `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_forensic.so`

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer.  Here's how to set that up in httpd.conf.  (Ugh, no linefeeds in comments??)

`LoadModule log_forensic_module /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_log_forensic.so`
`<IfModule log_forensic_module> ForensicLog /var/log/httpd/forensic_log </IfModule>`

Now you can check for [Shellshock](http://www.troyhunt.com/2014/09/everything-you-need-to-know-about.html) attempts like so: `grep "() {" /var/log/httpd/forensic_log`

Comment: Note, if you use `a2enmod log_forensic` to enable the module you don't need to use the `LoadModule` line.

Comment: I like to use LoadModule rather than a2enmod, because it can be activated only for an specific virtualhost, then I can just comment the line and reload apache, everything is back to normal!

Comment: In recent versions of apache or depending on your system, the path to the mod could be `/usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_log_forensic.so` and the typical folder to save the log would be `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/forensic.log`.

Comment: Thanks link update for apache 2.4 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_forensic.html

Answer (score 16):

Here is a list of all http-headers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

And here is a list of all apache-logformats: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats

As you did write correctly, the code for logging a specific header is %{foobar}i where foobar is the name of the header. So, the only solution is to create a specific format string. When you expect a non-standard header like x-my-nonstandard-header, then use `%{x-my-nonstandard-header}i`. If your server is going to ignore this non-standard-header, why should you want to write it to your logfile? An unknown header has absolutely no effect to your system.

Comment: It's still useful enough to be able to log all HTTP headers passed onto the apache machine. I would rather have a more flexible system than have to edit the `LogFormat` everytime a new header is introduced.

Comment: As noted in the linked article, a server may include non-standard, custom, application specific headers. This solution will *not* catch those if the person configuring Apache is unaware of them. As for an "unknown header having no effect on your system," you have *no* idea whether that's the case or not. Any number of web frameworks might leverage headers you didn't expect it to.

Comment: @Ehtesh I second that, being behind a load-balancer that modifies the headers.  I'd love to see exactly what I'm getting, something like %{i,*} with names.

Answer (score 9):

If you're interested in seeing which specific headers a remote client is sending to your server, and you can cause the request to run a CGI script, then the simplest solution is to have your server script dump the environment variables into a file somewhere.

e.g.  run the shell command "env > /tmp/headers" from within your script

Then, look for the environment variables that start with HTTP_...

You will see lines like:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.5
HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age=0
```

Each of those represents a request header.

Note that the header names are modified from the actual request. For example, "Accept-Language" becomes "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE", and so on.

Comment: Brilliant. So simple and straightforward, it flew under right everyone else's radar. `;)`

Answer (score 1):

In my case easiest way to get browser headers was to use php. It appends headers to file and prints them to test page.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('m:/temp/requests.txt', 'a');
$time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
fwrite($fp, $time + "\n");
echo "$time.<br>";
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    $cur_hd = "$name: $value\n";
    fwrite($fp, $cur_hd);
    echo "$cur_hd.<br>";
}
fwrite($fp, "***\n");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: I can't upvote this answer, because this isn't an answer to the OP. However, this also addresses my current use case, which also led me to this Q&A, so all I can do here is to say thanks and give you a virtual Thumbs Up.