# X-Forwarded-For not working in apache web server

Tags: apache, webserver, load-balancing, f5, x-forwarded-for

Good day,

The following is the architect diagram of my web project.

`Internet --> F5 Load balancer --> Apache web server --> web application`

I am trying to make the Apache web server receive the user ip from internet from the load balancer.

However, I found that the `Apache Web Server` is receiving `F5 ip` from `F5 Load balancer`, instead of user ip from internet.

Thus I open the `httpd.conf` from web server and configure the `X-Forwarded-For` setting inside, the following is the value I added inside `httpd.conf`:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
# The following line is added by me
LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy 

# I commented this following line
#CustomLog logs/access_log combined
# The following 3 lines is added by me
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined env=!forwarded
CustomLog "logs/access_log" proxy env=forwarded
```

I restart `apache` server but the result still the same. May I know anything I set wrong for the configuration?

Comment: Maybe you have another .conf file that takes precedence (it is common to have Virtual hosts defined in separate conf files)?

Comment: @DusanBajic, didnt see another .conf file. But I suspect F5 does not return the client ip to the web server, do u know how to check or how to log, so that I can know whether F5 returning me client ip?

Comment: In your logs, in field where you expect to see the client ip, do you see nothing or do you see f5 ip address?

Comment: Only see F5 ip address, but I not sure how to proof that F5 did not return the client IP, so plan to find this out first.

Comment: Change combined log format to include both: `LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l ...` and see what happens

Comment: You will not see the XFF header unless it is configured on the F5 LoadBalancer. The F5 LoadBalancer is a full proxy which means it initiates a completely new client connection to your server. It will not forward the XFF header unless it is configured to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to enable the `Insert X-Forwarded-For` option in the HTTP profile on the F5 Load Balancer:

```
Local Traffic > Profiles > HTTP
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's an image of the F5 WebUI.

Comment: Currently I have no access right to the F5, But I suspect F5 does not return the client ip to the web server, do u know how to check or how to log, so that I can know whether F5 returning me client ip?

Comment: If you are using *nix then use TCPDUMP to display the headers (https://www.fir3net.com/UNIX/Linux/how-to-display-http-headers-using-tcpdump.html) - If you are using windows then use wireshark to capture the traffic and see the HTTP headers. If there is no XFF HTTP header then the F5 BIGIP LoadBalancer is not inserting them.

Comment: The webserver is using Linux, however I am hitting tcpdump: command not found. Is there any way to check in web server log for this?

Comment: If you enable low level logging then you should be able to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948064/is-it-possible-to-log-all-http-request-headers-with-apache

Comment: I tried to integrate the @PaulDawson's comment into the answer but the suggestion queue is full now