# What is this error in Apache access log: "POST /ussd HTTP/1.1" 406 344 "-" "bf-am-http"?

Tags: php, apache, soap, ussd

I'm trying to build a USSD, the operator is sending me a SOAP request but the Apache access log is showing this error:

> OperatorIP - - [Timestamp] "POST /ussd HTTP/1.1" 406 344 "-" "bf-am-http"

The request is coming to `https://example.com/ussd.php`, (using RewriteRule to get rid of .php), and the `ussd.php` file contains these lines only:

```
#Get the inputs and log them to a file to see the contents
$requestBody = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
file_put_contents("ussdbody.json", $requestBody);
$requestServer = json_encode(array('data' => as $_SERVER));
file_put_contents("ussdserver.json", $requestServer);
echo "Welcome to the ussd";
```

If I access `https://example.com/ussd` with a web browser or Postman, `ussdbody.json` & `ussdserver.json` will be updated with the body & server content.
But when the operator sends the USSD request, nothing changes in those files and all I can see in the access log is the error above.

I even tried disabling firewalld thinking it might be a firewall issue, but nothing changed.

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be an extra ```)``` at the end of the first line?  i.e. ```trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));```

Comment: Why not check [the PHP error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel)? This could be a different log than the Apache access log.

Comment: @ewokx there is another ```)```, just accidentally dropped it here, cause my requests are working fine, but the requests coming from them aren't.

Comment: Assuming you verified that the PHP code CANNOT return a 406 status (implying that it really is httpd) you need to look at the request headers in the failing operation and compare this with the content negotiation config in your webserver. Without these we can't advise.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware the PHP error log shows this error: ```[negotiation:error] [pid xxxxx] [client IP:PORT] AH00690: no acceptable variant: example.com/ussd```.  Is it possible I misconfigured the ```.htaccess```? ```RewriteRule ^ussd& ussd.php [L]```

Comment: @symcbean that's the problem, the request isn't reaching the ```ussd.php``` script so I can't see what the content of the request is, can the headers be recorded somewhere else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948064/is-it-possible-to-log-all-http-request-headers-with-apache

Answer (score 0):

you have forgotten values to files that you create it, You can use this code:

```
$requestBody = trim(file_get_contents('php://input'));
file_put_contents("ussdbody.json",$requestBody);
$requestServer = json_encode(array('data' => $_SERVER));
file_put_contents("ussdserver.json",$requestServer);
echo "Welcome to the ussd";
```

Comment: My bad, I'm actually writing the values to the files correctly, but I wrote the code instead of copying it from the server and forgot to write them here. When I access the url with Postman or web browser, the content are getting written to the files correctly.